# Webkit и iframe в таблице

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, webkit

Chrome и новая Opera. При попытке отправки формы кнопка "убегала" от юзера за счёт постоянно разрастающейся таблицы:

```
<h1>Webkit only</h1>
<table>
    <tr style="line-height: 3em;">
        <td><span>AAA</span></td>
        <td>
            Here goes some text<br/>
            Here goes some more text<br/>            
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" border="1" scrolling="yes" src="http://www.google.ru"></iframe>
        </td>
    <tr style="line-height: 3em;">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            Here goes some more text<br/>
            Here goes some more text<br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Try to click it &mdash;&gt;</td>
            <td><button onclick="alert('Yes')">Click me!</button></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

[Пример на JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CamaroSS/v9L51j8s/13/)

Answer (score 1):

*<sup>Вынесенный ответ из тела вопроса</sup>*

Решение простое - задать ячейке с `iframe` фиксированную высоту:

```
<td rowspan="2" style="height: 200px">
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" border="1" scrolling="yes"
            src="http://www.google.ru"></iframe>
</td>
```

[Визуализация на JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CamaroSS/v9L51j8s/15/)

Удивительно, но никто не жаловался, пользователи Chrome мужественно охотились за кнопкой.